# Why did Takshaka appear before Utanka in the form of a naked beggar?

Tags: mahabharata

While giving away her ear rings, the queen of king Paushya, [she warns Utanka](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01004.htm) about King of Serpants, Takshaka, who is waiting to steal those ear rings.

> 'These ear-rings are very much sought after by Takshaka, the King of
> the serpents. Therefore shouldst thou carry them with the greatest
> care.'

On the road Utanka perceived coming towards him a ***naked idle beggar*** sometimes coming in view and sometimes disappearing. And Utanka put the ear-rings on the ground and went for water. In the meantime the beggar came quickly to the spot and taking up the ear-rings ran away.

> And Utanka having completed his ablutions in water and purified
> himself and having also reverently bowed down to the gods and his
> spiritual masters pursued the thief with the utmost speed.
>
> And having with great difficulty overtaken him, he seized him by
> force. But at that instant the person seized, quitting the form of a
> beggar and assuming his ***real form, viz., that of Takshaka,***
> speedily entered a large hole open in the ground.

My question is -

Why did Takshaka appear in the form of a naked beggar?  Does it indicate a pot shot against Jains/Buddhists?

or

Was it a common practice for beggars to move in nude?